# Add geometry column from exisiting x,y,z columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as such:

[image]

All columns are Decimal(18, 3), there are also millions of rows.

I would like to add a fourth column to be a geometry point. I have tried but to no avail:

```
 alter table [dbo].[o5bim] add ogr_geometry as geometry::STGeomFromText('Point('+column1+' '+column2+' '+column3+')', 0)
```

Driving me insane! Cheers

Comment: So what is happening when you try? I would *guess* you're getting an error along the lines of "varchar value 'Point(' cannot be converted to decimal."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @lptr [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70097617/add-geometry-column-from-exisiting-x-y-z-columns#comment123913624_70097617), you can use `STPointFromText`

```sql
alter table dbo.[o5bim]
  add ogr_geometry as
    geometry::STPointFromText(concat('POINT (', column1, ' ', column2, ' ', column3, ')'), 0);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f2fe881f01e606c182331f6a6e52ece9)